# rails generate migration table name command does not create migration in db/migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I am running 
`$ rails generate migration Tablename`
command in command prompt. Should I see the newly created table in db/migrate? I am new in rails.

I can see the following error:

```
rails generate migration TruncateUnusedTables
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:98:in `gets': Interrupt
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:98:in `verify_server_version'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `run'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:37:in `warm_run'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from .rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from .rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new in rails.

Welcome! We're here to help.

> Should I see the newly created table in db/migrate?

Not with `$ rails generate migration Tablename`. You will need to configure your migration such that the table is created. This is a big topic, so head over to the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to read up on generating migrations.